# Angr never finishes

Tags: angr

I create the following c program as a proof of concept. When I try to analyze it with anger it never finishes.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char *secret = "password";

int compare(char *string)
{
    int i, c=0;
    for (i=0; i< strlen(secret); i++)
    {
        if (string[i] == secret[i])
            c++;
    }
    if (c == 8)
        printf("You won");
    return 0;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char input[50];
    scanf("%s", input);
    compare(input);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The script is the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import angr
import sys
import logging
import claripy

FIND = 0x00000000000011dd
LEN = 8 

def basic_symbolic_execution():
    p = angr.Project('test', load_options={'auto_load_libs':False})

    flag = claripy.BVS('flag', LEN * 8)

    st = p.factory.entry_state(
        stdin=flag,
    )

    sm = p.factory.simulation_manager(st)
    sm.explore(find=FIND, num_find=1)

    print("Found solution")
    out = b''

    for pp in sm.deadended:
        out = pp.posix.dumps(1)
        print(out)

    import IPython; IPython.embed()

def test():
    r = basic_symbolic_execution()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(basic_symbolic_execution())
```

I have also tried to use explore on the address of c++ 8 times and then checking the stdin and it finishes but the result is all zeros. I was wondering if any of you have faced something similar and what your solutions were.

Comment: Hi, while this is fully on topic, you may want to consider [filing a ticket here](https://github.com/angr/angr/issues) as that's more likely to catch the attention of the Angr developers. Also, **your question isn't really a question**, it's more of a statement. You may want to edit it to clarify what you expect members of this site to contribute to your RCE effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By your FIND address it seems like your binary was compiled with PIE. Please verify this. Angr will load PIE enabled elf at a base address of 0x400000, add this to your FIND address so that angr is able to resolve this.

I have made a couple of changes to your script to make it detect the "password".

```
import angr
import sys
import logging
import claripy

FIND = 0x00400672
LEN = 8

def basic_symbolic_execution():
    p = angr.Project('x', load_options={'auto_load_libs':False})

    flag = claripy.BVS('flag', LEN * 8)

    st = p.factory.entry_state(
        stdin=flag,
    )

    sm = p.factory.simulation_manager(st)
    sm.explore(find=FIND, num_find=1)

    print("Found solution")
    out = b''

    for pp in sm.found:
        out = pp.posix.dumps(0)
        print(out)
        print(pp.solver.eval(flag, cast_to=str))

    import IPython; IPython.embed()

def test():
    r = basic_symbolic_execution()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    basic_symbolic_execution()
```

To look for states which actually reached your FIND addresses you need to iterate over `found` of a `simulation_manager`.

According to `man stdin`

> On  program  startup, the integer file descriptors associated with the streams stdin,
>          stdout, and  stderr  are  0,  1,  and  2,  respectively.

So to get input you need to use `pp.posix.dumps(0)`

I have also added on how to use `solver` of a found state to solve for constraints that you set like the `flag`.

Also offset for the printf in the binary for me.

```
$ gcc -no-pie -fno-pic x.c -o x
$ r2 -AA x -qc "pdf @ sym.compare ~won"    
│       │   0x00400672      bf7d074000     mov edi, str.You_won        ; 0x40077d ; "You won"
```

Comment: I tried your way with no luck. I also tried with sm.run() plainly and it logs

    """Exit state has over 256 possible solutions. Likely unconstrained; skipping. """

over and over and no solution is found.

Comment: @letFunny I have updated my answer.

Comment: It does work this way. However the problem with using sm.run() is the number of possible states (>500). How is that possible in such tiny program. When using num_find = 1 it finished thou.